# Are there any performance loss and lifespan risk for using NTFS on Linux?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

I often use a virtual machine to do something, but virtual hard disks are large and the SSD on my laptop is small. So I bought a 1TB HDD mobile hard drive to store most of my data. By default it is formatted to NTFS, and NTFS also has the best compatibility for Windows.

Since NTFS is not designed for Linux, are there any disadvantages of using NTFS on Linux everyday? Especially when I use virtual disks and have a lot of r/w. If not, what is the best file system choice for it?

I just don't want to reduce its lifespan.

Comment: I don't think you _can_ use NTFS on Linux. Edit: Never mind, I guess you can use NTFS on Linux. On another note, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546896/performance-difference-ntfs-linux-and-ntfs-windows?rq=1) question.

Comment: @saiarcot895: sure you can.

Comment: I doubt that Linux NTFS drivers notably affect the lifespan of hard disks. The main issues are compatibility, performance, and maybe bugs that may corrupt the file system.

Comment: @Takkat I think this question only partly qualifies as a duplicate. The main question regarding the safety of NTFS on Linux hasn't been posted on AU, yet, as far as I can see. You are right about the second part regarding alternatives to NTFS. 黄凯哲, how about modifying your question so that you take out the section about alternatives to NTFS. That would allow us to remove the duplicate status.

Comment: @Glutanimate: e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/32292/is-ntfs-3g-safe-for-writing http://askubuntu.com/questions/164728/should-i-choose-exfat-or-ntfs-for-a-shared-partition-in-a-dual-boot-system of course ext4 is better... but there is little choice when it comes to sharing a drive with Windows.

Comment: @Takkat Yep, those are clear duplicates. Thanks! It really is a shame we haven't been able to establish a universal modern non patent-encumbered  file system, yet.